# Can't connect to database file ( mdf )

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I wrote simple winform ( part of it with WPF ). 
In the simple application i have some place that i get information from database ( from mdf file ).

The code ..

```
public SomeDBObject : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
     ... some code ...
}

List< SomeDBObject > listViewItem = null;
try
{
    listViewItem = new List< SomeDBObject >();

    using( DBDataContext dBDataContext = new DBDataContext( mdf_File_Path_String ) )
    {
        listViewItem.AddRange( from item in dBDataContext.dBs
                               select ( SomeDBObject ) item );
    }
}
catch( Exception e )
{
     ... 
}
```

now, on my machine and on some other machine all work fine.

But some on some other machine that i install ( clean machine ) my application i get exception from the line

```
    using( DBDataContext dBDataContext = new DBDataContext( mdfFilePathString ) )
```

and the exception is about some problem with the sql on the machine.

The exception:

a database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on unc share.

This is happaning with win7 and win Xp also.

I try to re-install the sql 2008 express - but this is not halping.

Comment: yes, tryed it ... not fixing the problem :(

Comment: And the application is using the same security context?

Comment: yes, the secutity context is same.